# Backend is just called once

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, spring-mvc, freemarker

I am working over a Spring-MVC web based application.
I use Freemarker as well as JQuery.
@Freemarker,I have the following JQuery that it should go to the back end twice:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();
    $.getJSON('[@spring.url '/vacation/loadResourceVacation'/]', function (data) {
      $.getJSON('[@spring.url '/vacation/loadPublicVacations'/]', function (returnedPublicVacation) {....
```

The 2 java methods are :

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/loadResourceVacation", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public
  @ResponseBody
  String loadResourceVacation(HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    // Convert to JSON string.
    String json = new Gson().toJson(myObject);

    // Write JSON string.
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    return json;
  }


@RequestMapping(value = "/loadPublicVacations", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public
  @ResponseBody
  String loadPublicVacations(HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    // Convert to JSON string.
    String json = new Gson().toJson(someObj);

    // Write JSON string.
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    return json;
  }
```

@Google Chrom,it works super fine.
However @ IE,it works fine for the first time I load the page.
If I tried to load page again ,the 2 methods won't be called and it'd be cached from the first time.

If I closed the session and opened a new session,the 2 methods would be called again.
Any help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) says:

> cache - Boolean
>
> Default: true, false for dataType 'script' and 'jsonp'
>
> If set to false, it will force requested pages not to be cached by the browser. Setting cache to false also appends a query string parameter, "_=[TIMESTAMP]", to the URL.

Comment: Exactly ... jQuery.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });